# Harvest honey without damaging brood cells

Tags: cell-biology, zoology, reproduction

I want to make a homemade beehive, I want to know how to differentiate honey cells and brood cells, therefore, I'd like to know how can I organize the beehive so bees will create honey and brood cells separately. By this way, I would be able to harvest the honey without killing the larvaes :)

Ancillary issues : Do bees need cells to sleep in ? Can I populate a homemade beehive with several bees caught from my garden ?

Thank you for your attention :)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I do not think this question is really about biology (but wait to get other users' opinion). You might want to consider pet.SE and sustainableLiving.SE (or even maybe greatOutdoor.SE).

Comment: You may have better luck on beekeeping speciality site like this https://beebuilt.com/pages/beekeeping-for-beginners

Comment: I think this question is about applied use of biological knowledge, more specifically bee behavior and entomology, and should be re-opened. Closing it is to me similar to closing general questions on medical treatments or medicine, since they are "just" applications of biology/biochemistry and not "really about biology" per se. Which we do not do at Bio-SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In domesticated bee hives, this is usually accomplished by excluding the queen from a section of hive frames (by the size of the entrance hole), so that these frames only contain honey and no eggs/larvae.
For instance, this can be achieved using a [queen excluder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_excluder).